# CDaoRecordSet select all from column

Tags: c++, mfc

How can i store all the records of a column in a `CDaoRecordSet`? I've tried this, but will only return the first record of that column:

```
rs.Open(dbOpenSnapshot, "SELECT Numar_inmatriculare FROM Masini");
short nFields = rs.GetFieldCount();//returns 1
```

If i make a `"SELECT count(*) AS Numar_inmatriculare FROM Masini"` and use `rs.GetFieldValue(0)` it returns me 13, the correct number of records.

Comment: Show the other code where you are determining that you only got one row.  The RecordSet object only exposes one row at a time, you must call Move or a Find... function to advance to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFieldCount` returns the number of columns in your resultset.

To iterate through the records (=rows), you have to call `MoveNext` until `IsEOF()` returns true.

```
rs.Open(dbOpenSnapshot, "SELECT Numar_inmatriculare FROM Masini");

while(!rs.IsEOF())
{
    // do something
    rs.MoveNext();
}
```